# Diffie hellman and the discrete algorithm problem

Tags: calculus, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, logarithms

Suppose Alice and Bob are exchanging keys using Diffie-Hellman Key-Exchange Algorithm.
a - Alice secret key
g - generator
p - prime
x - the public key passed from Alice to Bob.

Eve is listening to the communication and she is exposed to the three parameters g,p,x.
She's using a brute-force method to find $a$, Alice's secret key.
Thus, Eve is looking for $a$ satisfying this equation:
$${g^a}\bmod p = x$$

Now, I know (By testing) Eve can find $a' \ne a$ satisfying the equation above, and by using $a'$ she can also compute the common secret key used by Alice and Bob.

Why is it mathematically true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the secret number chosen by Bob be $b$. During exchange, Bob will send $y=g^b\bmod p$ to Alice.

The common secret key obtained after the protocol, $k$, is $g^{ab}\bmod p$. If Eve has another $a'$ that satisfies $g^{a'}\bmod p = g^a\bmod p$, then she can still perform what Alice would do after listening to $y$:

$$\begin{align*}
k' =& y^{a'}\bmod p\\
=& \left(g^b\right)^{a'}\bmod p\\
=& \left(g^{a'}\right)^{b}\bmod p\\
=& \left(g^a\right)^{b}\bmod p\\
=& k
\end{align*}$$

Which is the same as what Alice and Bob would get.